# Angular set a formControlName value from a nested json

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

So here is what I want to do, I have this model that I converted into a FormGroup and its based on a JSON structure, now I want to get data from one of the values into an input but I have no luck getting it so far. This is what I have right now.

```
export class SaleTemplateComponent implements OnInit {
currencies: Currency[] = [];

movement: Movement = new Movement();

movementForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private _currency: CurrencyService,
            private _stakeholder: StakeholderService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshData();
    this.movementForm = new FormGroup({
        'id': new FormControl(this.movement.id, [ Validators.required ]),
        'stakeholderId': new FormControl(this.movement.stakeholderId, [ Validators.required ]),
        'stakeholder': new FormControl(this.movement.stakeholder),
        'currencyId': new FormControl(this.movement.currencyId, [ Validators.required ]),
        'currency': new FormControl(this.movement.currency),
    });
}
```

The currency and stakeholder FormControls are full nested models of the movement FormGroup, something like this:

```
export class Movement {
    public id: number;
    public currencyId: number;
    public currency: Currency;
    public stakeholderId: number;
    public stakeholder: Stakeholder;
}

export class Currency {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
}

export class Stakeholder {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
}
```

Now I got the html part like this so far but it doesnt work:

```
<form [formGroup]="movementForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <h4>Informacion del documento</h4>
            <div class="form-body">
                <label>Documento de Identidad</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="stakeholderId">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-body">
                <label>Nombre / Razon Social</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControl]="{{ stakeholder.name }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

What I want to do is to get the value from the stakeholder name nested inside that formControl, but so far after several tests I cant seem to get it. The value is not obtained on ngOnInit() it can only be obtained just after the stakeholderId is typed cuz it calls a (change) method.

Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it won't work is because you're trying to pass an object into a form control which should only be a singular value.

In your form you have `stakeholder` defined as a form control like this

```
'stakeholder': new FormControl(this.movement.stakeholder),
```

you have `movement.stakeholder` defined as this object

```
export class Stakeholder {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
}
```

If you want to use the stakeholder's name as  the value for the form control you need to define the `stakeholder` field in your form like this

```
stakeholder: new FormControl(this.movement.stakeholder.name, [Validators.required]),
```

However if you want the entire `stakeholder` object as a part of your form then you should make a `FormGroup` out of it like this

```
stakeholder: new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl(this.movement.stakeholder.id, [Validators.require]),
    name: new FormControl(this.movement.stakeholder.name, [Validators.required])
}),
```

If you just want to use the `name` property as the FormControl value you would just access it in the template like this

```
<input type="text" formControlName="stakeholder" />
```

or if you want to go with the 2nd option you'd need to encapsulate the `<input />` inside of another element to define a FormGroup which would look something like this.

```
<div [formGroup]="stakeholder">
    <input type="text" formControlName="name" />
</div>
```

You should be able to access the value after setting it up one of these ways.